# learning android UI creation

Tags: android

I am a `C# Windows Phone developer` and right now i am exploring `android` to expand my learning horizon in mobile technologies. But I am finding it difficult to get UI part of the android. I tried a lot but 
have some some issue :-

- What I am not sure how what is good way to learn it.
- There are lots of screen are out there how can I make a  common UI
  for all the screens ? Best practices for this part.

I have understand the concepts of android and how app really works but i am not able to getting good at UI part. because everytime I try for UI i thought that It is not a good way.

I know people here are the learners and can share their experience to learn me in a good way :)

this question may inappropriate but all I need is some help in right direction. cheers :)

any help and pointers are appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the official guides for Android development in http://developer.android.com/. Here, you can find all the best practices about different resolutions, densities, colours and many other guides. I strongly recommend you to check the training guide over [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: My confusions are big ones like -  how to choose between what layout should be used e.g linear layout, relative,frame etc. I am just getting confused in them. Can I have your comment about them ?

Comment: In my opinion, it depends on what you want to achieve. If you didn't, you can read more about the layers over [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Comment: suppose I have created a textview and an image view and set them using relative layout and also set their height/width using dp concept. will it work fine for all the devices ?

Comment: No, it won't, because you have to have [Different Screen Sizes Support](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)